# Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb AFTER virutalenv

Tags: python, mysql, django, virtualenv, mysql-python

Ok I have been pouring over this site and google but cannot find the right answer. I should start by mentioning I'm new to this stuff.

I had a django project 90 percent done. I am building it in Linux with a virtualenv.   For some reason when I was in the project directory I decided to type 'virualenv .'   Not sure what this did, assuming it overwrote my current settings, but now everything is broke. I'm trying to fix it all. I am using python 2.7, but I am getting the following traceback:

```
    enter code here  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 330, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/IPNV/django-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb.
```

I have troubleshot this every way I can. I have tried apt-get pip with mysqldb-python, the connect everything. What am I missing?????

Comment: Using the command virtualenv alone shouldn't break down anything since it should only list you the available options to use along with it. I'm assuming you get that error when you start the server. Are you inside the virtualenvironment when running it?

Comment: The command was 'virtualenv .'   With the period. - Yes it breaks when I either run server or migrate. I found a work around but I really cannot understand what I did.

Comment: Are all dependencies installed inside the virtualenv? Are you using pip? If so try pip freeze to see if everything you need is there.